# Should the pandas at accessor work with multiindexes?

Tags: python, pandas

```
def gen():
    yield '1','2',1,2
    yield '1','2',1,2
    yield '1','3',1,2
    yield '2','4',1,2

df = pd.DataFrame(gen(), columns=["a", "b", "c", "d",]).set_index(["a", "b"])
print df   # ('a','b') --> ('c','d')
```

We have:

```
     c  d
a b      
1 2  1  2
  2  1  2
  3  1  2
2 4  1  2
```

When accessing:

```
print df.loc[('1','3')]  # Success
print df.at[('1','3')]   # KeyError: '3'
```

Also note, this also fails is df is a series:

```
print df['c'].at[('1','3')]   # TypeError: _get_value() got multiple values for keyword argument 'takeable'
```

Comment: `at` is for accessing scalars. `df.loc[('1','3')]` returns a row (a Series). You are not able to access only by row index if it is not a MultiIndex either. Try `df.at[('1', '3'), 'c']` (I am not sure why this returns an array - might be a bug).

Comment: But it also breaks in the same way if df is a series (if I do df = df['c'])

Comment: Yeah that also looks like a bug.

Comment: It seems like `at` and `iat` do not support MultiIndex but they don't raise appropriate errors when called on a MultiIndex: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9259